# Is it possible to use different libraries as git submodules in a turborepo?

Tags: reactjs, git, next.js, git-submodules, turborepo

I am trying to use a git repo with a few UI components as package in turborepo, adding the package immediately by using `git submodule add` did not help

is there a way to use submodules inside turborepo?